# aligned in multline*, gather*, or align* produces superfluous space

Tags: align, mathtools, multline, gather

Somewhat related to [aligned in multlined produces superfluous space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661362) , there is superfluous space inside `multline*`, `gather*`, or `align*` if its contents contains `aligned` with at least two columns. Namely, feeding `pdflatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  (
    \begin{aligned}[c]
      &\text{an arbitrarily complex formula}
    \end{aligned}
  )
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

yields space between the contents of the `aligned` environment and the closing right paren:

[image: output]

An underfull `\hbox` is reported to the console.

Who is the culprit and what to do?  In other words, where does this space come from and how to get rid of it in a different way than adding some hard-coded negative space (such as `\mskip-19mu`) manually? Of course, you may say

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  (
    \begin{alignedat}[c]{1}
      &\text{an arbitrarily complex formula}
    \end{alignedat}
    )
  \end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

and get rid of the space:

[image: output]

Still, an underfull `\hbox` as well as the problem with the original `align` remain.

Comment: ` &\text{an arbitrarily complex formula}\\ ` gets rid of the space but underfull box, still not right

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interestingly, even without \\, an underfull \hbox is reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is *always* generated by `aligned` and it's immaterial where it's embedded in. Your example can be reduced to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$(\begin{aligned} a&=b \end{aligned})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The extra space usually goes unnoticed, but not when `aligned` is used like that. The effect is expected, when one looks at how `aligned` is defined, in particular where the preamble for the internal `\halign` is generated:

```
        \ialign\bgroup
           &\column@plus
            \hfil
            \strut@
            $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$%
            \tabskip\z@skip
           &\column@plus
            $\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$%
            \hfil
            \tabskip\alignsep@
            \crcr
```

where one clearly sees the `\tabskip\alignsep@` at the end. Basically, `aligned` generates pairs of columns, typeset in display style;

- first column aligned right,
- no intervening horizontal space because of `\tabskip\z@skip`,
- second column aligned left, with an empty atom at the beginning,
- horizontal space of width `\alignsep@`.

The last space is the price to pay for being able to typeset an arbitrary number of pairs of columns.

If you want precise control of the space, use `alignedat`.

The value of `\alignsep@` is usually set to `\minalignsep` and we can see it at work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$(\begin{alignedat}{1} a&=b \end{alignedat})$

$(\begin{aligned} a&=b \end{aligned})$

$(\displaystyle a=b\hspace{\minalignsep})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not sure this is the whole story though,`$(\begin{aligned} a&=b \\\end{aligned})$` has no space (and no extra row) well, it unskips, but shouldn't end{aligned} ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, it's not the full story. With more than two columns the space appears and disappears in “random” situations.

Comment: First, thanks a lot! Second, it's a bit unsatisfactory for the space to be, erm, random, and, what's worse, undocumented. I could post a bug report against `mathtools`, if wished… Yes, `alignedat` solves the issue for me the typesetter.